# Can NVIDIA Nsight still be used to debug shaders?

Tags: opengl, gpu, nvidia, nsight

Numerous online resources claim it is possible to debug OpenGL shaders using [NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition). Here is an [old video](https://youtu.be/HAm5ziXE6pA?t=937) of it being done.

However, the Nsight VSE page mentions "*the integrated Graphics Frame Debuggers and integrated Profilers have been removed*" and I have been unable to find a way to add breakpoints to Shaders/Programs in the [NVIDIA Nsight Graphics](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-graphics) - Frame Debugger (the standalone replacement for the integrated version). I can view the shader code and even edit it, but not add a breakpoint. Is this still possible in any way from within Nsight Graphics or some other program?

Possibly even an old install?

[image]